# How to build docker file for a VueJs application

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I am new in docker. I've built an application with VueJs2 that interacts with an external API. I would like to run the application on docker.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:

    ew_cp:
        image: vuejs_img
        container_name: ew_cp
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - '.:/app'
            - '/app/node_modules'
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node"]
```

Here is the building command I run to build my image an container.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The image and container is building without error but when I run the container it stops immediately. So the container is not running.
Are the DockerFile and compose files set correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you run `npm install` and `yarn install`, which is doing the same thing, just using different package managers. Secondly you are using `CMD ["node"]` which does not start your vue application, so there is no job running and docker is shutting down.

For vue applicaton you normally want to build the app with static assets and then run a simple http server to serve the static content.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server
# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app
# copy 'package.json' to install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
# install dependencies
RUN npm install
# copy files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .
# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Your `docker-compose` file could be as simple as

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  vue-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: vue-app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - vue-network
networks:
  vue-network:
    driver: bridge
```

to run the service from docker-compose use `command` property in you `docker-compose.yml`.

```
services:
  vue-app:
    command: >
      sh -c "yarn serve"
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working but when I add `RUN yarn serve` the image won't get created unless I remove the `RUN yarn serve` and then I `exec` into the built container and `RUN yarn serve` manually. Is there anyway to get this fixed?

Comment: you can also run the service via docker-compose.  I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Sidenote for Mac M1 Users: If you get an Error something like `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error` **CHANGE** your `FROM:`. For Example if you defined `FROM: node:14-alpine`, extend it to `FROM: --platform=linux/amd64 node:14-alpine`. The reason is the codeset that docker uses. If you have more questions, please tag me so I can read it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the problem but by using `command: tail -f /dev/null` in your `docker-compose` file , it will keep up your container so you could track the error within it and find its problem. You could do that by running `docker exec -it <CONTAINER-NAME> bash`  and track the error logs in your container.

```sh
version: '3'

services:

    ew_cp:
        image: vuejs_img
        container_name: ew_cp
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - '.:/app'
            - '/app/node_modules'
    
        command: tail -f /dev/null

        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
```

In your `Dockerfile` you have to start your application e.g. `npm run start` or any other scripts that you are using for running your application in your `package.json`.

Comment: you should not run `npm run dev` in docker, if you want to use the file for production deployment. this would just be useful to have streamlined development environment. but even then it's better to use env file to check how to run the service.

Comment: I edited it, but I meant for the development, and generally, the main script for running the app was my point.